# Postgres: get count of users who have taken trial and taken paid subscription on weekly basis

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know the title is not helpful sorry for that. I am lost, as i don't know what i am looking for filtering data.

Here is my Subscription schema

```
id user_id type sub_type created_at
1 1 A trial August 1, 2021, 12:00 AM
2 2 A trial August 8, 2021, 12:00 AM
3 3 A trial August 8, 2021, 12:00 AM
4 1 A paid August 8, 2021, 12:00 AM
5 2 A paid August 8, 2021, 12:00 AM
```

I want to know on weekly basis how many users took trial and how many of them taken paid subscription. sort of like this

```
week      trial paid
August 1   1     1
August 8   2     1
```

I got weekly trial by this query

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', created_at::date) AS weekly,
       COUNT(user_id)
FROM subscription
WHERE sub_type = 'trial'
GROUP BY weekly
ORDER BY weekly;
```

I am new to db queries and not sure if i should be using join or sub queries. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation, which in Postgres is best done using `filter`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', created_at::date) AS weekly,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sub_type = 'trial') as num_trials,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sub_type = 'paid') as num_paid
FROM subscription
GROUP BY weekly
ORDER BY weekly;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, this is useful. but this gives me paid subscriptions in that particular week. I want paid subscriptions from the trial users cohort. they can take subscriptions a month later also, date does not matter while counting paid subscription. it is for conversion purpose that how many users took paid subscriptions from a set of trial users. Thanks for the answer, i will explore filter.